# Output to printable file 3D model

Tags: modeling, error, 3d-printing

so i created a really detailed model of what I need 3D printed. but when I try to export it to a 3D printing software it does not do what I want.

It creates infill in spots that I specificly designed to be empty,

it makes up empty layers, while in my model in blender its completely filled

it just in general does not do what I want.

I made the model with exact sizes that it needs to be etc. I really could use the help.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Please add a detailed description of the problems. And please keep it one problem per question, you can post as many separate questions as you need :).

Comment: Hello, the 3D Print Toolbox addon shipped with blender has handy operations to make sure your mesh is suited for 3D printing. You should check it out

Answer (score 0):

I exported the file as an STL into Cura, and I saw your problem. The way I fixed it was by adding a solidify modifier to both of the meshes. You don't need to add a lot of thickness, but you do need some (I added 0.02 m).

Let me know if it works.